# Outlook App failing to override background color in dark mode for divs in email

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I am trying to fix the emails for dark mode in Outlook App. For some reason when in dark mode outlook fails to override the background-color however it correctly overrides the font color, this leads to emails with white background and white text in dark mode. It works fine on browser just the IOS app has this issue.
I want to know how i can indicate the App what it should override the background color to.
my html code, i have tried both inline styling and css class, both have same issue

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="footer" style="background-color: white;">
            <p class='h5-regular'>
                Some Text
                <br />
                <p class='h5-regular'>
                    Some Text
                </p>
            </p>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different email clients deal with dark mode differently.

Outlook iOS app supports the @media prefers-color-scheme feature, so you can add your desired code to the `<head>` (https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-media-prefers-color-scheme/)

```
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
<meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark">
<style>
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark ) {
  .footer { background-color: #000000 !important; }
  p { color: #ffffff !important; }
}
</style>
```

The meta tags tell the rendering engine that you support both light and dark themes.

See https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-dark-mode-for-email-marketers/ for further context

Comment: it works perfectly on phone but then the browser outlook on my desktop also applies this additional css. so i end up with white text in light mode on desktop

Comment: i changed it to nested media query and added the condition that the above css is only active on phone screens. it does the job. However i don't understand why the outlook app doesn't show the correct color for the HEX code i put in. its a very light shade of the Hex code (#373737) i put in which is not what i want. it works fine if i use black or red.

Comment: So, the background colour goes to #373737 when you have #000000? There may be a specific trigger--try #000001.  Most dark modes do not use #000000 because they find it's a bit too dark: too much contrast can be difficult to read.

Comment: No i want the background color to be #373737 (dark grey) but its changing to #bdbdbd (very light grey), i assumed when i add background color with !important and dark mode media query, outlook app wont overwrite it anymore, so kinda confused here.

Comment: Email clients do the strangest things. They all have their quirks, and dark mode manipulation is no exception!